# How to create a simple program in python to test the interface I created in Glade?

Tags: python, user-interface, pycharm, glade

I'm just getting into creating python programs with GUIs. After spending about several hours trying to get Glade to work on Mac, I have finally created my first `.glade` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkNotebook">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLayout">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel">
                <property name="width_request">100</property>
                <property name="height_request">80</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">label</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="x">158</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="btnOne">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">One</property>
                <property name="width_request">160</property>
                <property name="height_request">34</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="margin_right">1</property>
                <property name="action_name">btnOneAction</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="x">126</property>
                <property name="y">56</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child type="tab">
          <object class="GtkLabel">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">One</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="tab_fill">False</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child type="tab">
          <object class="GtkLabel">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">page 2</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="position">1</property>
            <property name="tab_fill">False</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child type="tab">
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

I've created a python 2.7 project in PyCharm, and based on a tutorial I found I created the following `.py` file to try and run the program with the interface:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

try:
    import pygtk
    pygtk.require("2.0")
except:
    pass
try:
    import gtk
    import gtk.glade
except:
    sys.exit(1)


class main:
    """This is an Hello World GTK application"""

    def __init__(self):
        # Set the Glade file
        self.gladefile = "gui.glade"
        self.wTree = gtk.glade.XML(self.gladefile)

        # Create our dictionay and connect it
        dic = {"on_btnHelloWorld_clicked": self.btnHelloWorld_clicked,
               "on_MainWindow_destroy": gtk.main_quit}
        self.wTree.signal_autoconnect(dic)

    def btnHelloWorld_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Hello World!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hwg = main()
    gtk.main()
```

Unfortunately, I don't really understand the code, and when I run it all that happens is the console outputs "`Process finished with exit code 1`"

So, there are no errors, but I'm still not able to run the program and see the interface I built.

Keep in mind the `.glade` file (`gui.glade`) has already been imported into the project, and is in the same directory as this `.py` file (`main.py`).

All I want to do is make a program in PyCharm that uses the Glade interface I built and have imported -- at this stage at the very least, I just need to figure out how to make it so that when PyCharm runs `main.py`, my interface is displayed.

Please help, thanks

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of debugging. PyCharm has a debugger. Turn it on, and walk through your code until it fails.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have used Glade 3.20 and then imported pygtk on your python file. PyGtk targets Gtk+ 2.0, to use Gtk+ 3.0 you must use PyGObject.

Then, when you use Glade you should give an ID to the widgets you plan to retrieve (will be easier if you do so).

This being said, i've added a ID to your Gtk.Window in the glade file:

```
...
<object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
...
```

Using the code below you can, easily, test the layout. Just change the glade file name to whatever you've used (`gui.glade`):

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("gui.glade")

window = builder.get_object("window1")
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

The result should look like this:

[image]